# Round image corner using custom widget

Tags: android, imageview, rounded-corners

i want to get rounded corners for images in a custom list. I used the custom widget method mentioned in the following link:

http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2011/08/quick-rounded-corners/#comments

The image corner is getting blurred. Can any body give me a  solution to have smooth corners using this mentod.

Answer (score 0):

Make one file in drawable folder. Name any thing to it. And set the `imageview` background by using that file. It will give you a round corner.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<stroke android:width="1dip"
    android:color="@color/stroke_color"/>

<solid android:color="@color/white"/>

<padding 
    android:left="5dip"
    android:top="5dip"
    android:right="5dip"
    android:bottom="5dip" />

<corners android:radius="5dip" />

</shape>
```

Comment: i tried this, but the image is not filling the width. the image and shape is having different width. so the shape is standing out.